# Eager Loading of Associations using MongoMapper

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I'm looking to Eager Load Associated Documents using MongoMapper. Say I have an author with a :has_one condition to a Post, I should be able to load the author using a single query

```
Post.find(:all, :include => :author)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: On the same topic, it would be great if I could have the same for an array of *embedded* objects which in turn have associations. Ex.: `question = Question.first; question.comments(:include => :user)` (where comments is an embedded model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The code below is just as models workflow.. I tried it after some coding and it didnt work!

Lets say you have Post model and User model.

User has_many posts, and you want All the users (authors) with their posts.

Here a tip to handle it. and my example is fetching one post.

post.rb

```
class Post
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :title, String
  key :body, String
  key :user_id, ObjectId

  belongs_to :user

end
```

and user.rb

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name
  many :posts, :embed => :title
end
```

Now,

```
u = User.first
p = u.posts.first

puts p.title # read it from embedded doc
puts p.body # lazy loading
```

The trick here is to embed the mostly common fields like the name of the user, _id, user slug, etc.

**I didnt test what above, but you have to give a try!**

Best
--Amr

Comment: Wish there was a simpler way but will take what I can get

Comment: I tried it for real! (after fixing and adding some codes) But unfortunately it didnt work. I think theres a chance in Mongoid, see this pull request: http://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/391